# Out-File or Set-Content format is not same as console output

Tags: powershell

The output that I see on the console looks different from what gets redirected to the file

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic Put BASE64 encoded value of username:password")

$response = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://abc123.com/feeds/feed_ipv4' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers

$response.content

#------------------------------

$response.content | set-content -Path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc.com\feed_IPV4.txt"

$response.content | out-file -FilePath "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc.com\feed_IPV4.txt"
```

Below is what is see in console for $response.content

```
1.1.1.1-1.1.1.10
2.2.2.2-2.2.2.20
```

Below is what is written to file by either set-content or out-file

```
1.1.1.1-1.1.1.102.2.2.2-2.2.2.20
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What does `$response.content.GetType()` yield? This is quite odd..

Comment: Add this somewhere in your script and run it again.
`Write-Host ([Console]::Out.Encoding.EncodingName) -ForegroundColor Cyan` What is your console encoding ? I suspect a discrepancy in the encoding ... Try setting the encoding of `Out-File` to the same thing of your console and / or try other encoding to see if different encoding produce the new line properly.

Comment: How many items does `$response.content` count? (`$response.content.count`)

Comment: What is `($response.content).GetType()`?  Shouldn't you be using `$response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked.

```
$response.content.split() | out-file -FilePath "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc.com\feed_IPV4.txt"
```